# How to pass values to another webpage's text fields?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a page with two text fields for username and password and a button. Now when the user clicks the button I want the page to redirect to another webpage and put the values(which user has inputted on my page) on that redirected webpage's text fields that would ask for the same. Now here my webpage is a basic page created by me, but the page that is to be redirected when user clicks the button would be a actual running website(that I don't have any control of). Languages & libraries that I have used are php, javascript, jquery, html, css. Are there any ways to make this happen ?..... Thanks in advance..... ... .. . This is my Attempt...

```
<html>
<head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function load()
    {
      var user = document.getElementById("tx1").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("tx2").value;
    // alert(user);
    // window.location.assign('');
    window.location="https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf?j_username="+user+"&password="+pass;
    // window.location.href = '';
    sessionStorage.user = user;
    sessionStorage.pass = pass;
    // alert(userid);
    }


        </script>

        </head>

    <body>
      <div id="dv001">
      <div id="dv11">

          <h2 id="txt2">Sign in</h2>
      <form>
          <b id="txt3">Have an account? <br> Sign in here..</b>
      <input type="text" id="tx1">

      <input type="password" id="tx2" >
          <!-- <a href="main_index.php"> -->
          <input type="Button" id="bt1" value="Sign in" onclick="load()">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this, i have tested it and it works fine

```
<form action="https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf" method="get">
<input type="text" name="j_username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: if the above solution solves your problem then mark it as answered .

Comment: Hey Thanks... i tried the above method and yes it does work.Both email and password are there in the URL but the password is doesn't show up in the text field. @Adern Nerk

Comment: @saurabh i filled the form and found irctc servers are under maintenance please check

Comment: from 03rd FEB 2018 23:59 HRS TO 04th Apr 2018 01:00 HRS IST (GMT + 05:30).

Comment: else wise this method will 100% work , or maybe they have used some jquery to block such parameters such that it will only work when the form filled by their website only not by any other outer resource

Comment: Since they were under maintenance, I tried some other URL i.e. facebook .... So the whole problem was on facebook's url.... @Adern Nerk

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to a page belonging to a different domain, you can't do anything to that page from JavaScript in your page. It is completely another browser window(sort of), on which you will have no access to it.

> The only one possibility is if the website uses $_GET to fill its
>   forms.

So, that you can fill in the [not in my control]domain link with few params from your page and navigate.

Comment: ...So is there any other way that i can do it, through any other language. But here I need PHP related help cuz all my database work is done by me in PHP....so is there a way to do it in PHP...?

Comment: In short: No. You can't access and modify a webpage of external domains unless they allow you to do so.

But, Since it is indianrailways website and if it allows you to pass GET parameters, then you should try their API documentaion. But I have searched for it and they don't seem to provide the functionality to login through API. So No..No..

Comment: So, can you explain what you are trying to achieve actually? Maybe I can help.

Comment: Now, the above text fields which I have mentioned will be in my project's "Edit Profile" option. Where user will fill the required fields(i.e. name, gender, age , etc.) and with them the user will also fill the username and password fields and in turn this all the entered data will be saved in my DB on a click of save button. Now whenever the user next time visits my page and clicks on that particular website that is through my page(i.e. my project) then the values which are in there in my DB will show up on that particular website's text fields. So here is what i exactly need.Thanks.. @spirit

Comment: So, are you building some kind of Chrome extension?

Comment: You can't do it unless it is an extension.
And as of what you are working on, is completely an extension, which has access to the browsers pages form any domain and you will be storing the  userid and passwords of the users, so that they can easily login to websites without worrying to remember passwords. Right??

So, try building an extension. It will help with what you want to achieve. But no website.

Comment: yeah you got my point there...see all my of project UI is in HTML, CSS, jQuery, JavaScript, etc and for database I am using PHP....so is there any way I can make this happen...I mean I just need to show those values in those text fields...that's it... @spirit

Comment: You can place the same page inside a chrome extension. You can use your server database to store passwords and retrieve them when needed. Read their documentation. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted